# Blazor - Web Components - WebAssembly - Micro frontends

Tags: asp.net, razor, web-component, webassembly

I'm investigating about Micro Front Ends and being able to have features built in different technologies. So far, creating Web Components and using those on the Monolith is the best approach I have found. 
Looking into different ways on creating Web Components and serving the modules in different services has being a fun experience.

Looking into WebAssembly with Blazor, I got a question: Can you create and host on a server a Web Component wrap in a Web Assembly? I try enable CORS and just copying the default html to a different file and running the static html from there but a root file is not found.

Is there a way to achieve something similar? Am I trying to use several technologies on ways it was not meant to and just making a mess?

Comment: We use AWS CloudFront CDN to serve all our assets for our micro frontend app. I would think this would work as well for WebAssembly.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68889811/1768303