# Is it possible to use Blazor Server Side Razor components with Micro Frontends?

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side, micro-frontend, razor-components

I am using the micro-frontends (https://micro-frontends.org/) client side architecture.  I am interested in Razor components (server side rendered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0), but it doesn't look like its possible to support micro-frontends with Razor components.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I did see this answer, but it is related to WebAssembly (using Blazor on client side): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108980/blazor-web-components-webassembly-micro-frontends